# how can one compile .vhd under ghdl?

Tags: compilation, makefile, vhdl, ghdl

My first question :  **I wonder how you compile your vhdl file under ghdl ?**

In c/c++, we use

- -Werror
- -Wunused-variable
- -Wunused-value
- -Wunused-function
- -Wfloat-equal -Wall

.My second question : are there a way one can use ghdl with those things ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [user manual](http://ghdl.free.fr/site/uploads/Main/ghdl_user_guide/AA_ghdl_guide.html) for GHDL would be a good starting point, specifically sections 3.1 (building) and 3.4 (warnings).

It is difficult to compare a set of C/C++ compiler flags to that of a VHDL compiler, but there may be some similar functionality between them, such as warnings become errors and alerting the user to unused design components. For example (from the documentation):

```
--warn-unused
   Emit a warning when a subprogram is never used. 
--warn-error
   When this option is set, warnings are considered as errors.
```

Comment: Unfortunately `--warn-unused` does not seem to catch unused signals. I haven't discovered a way to catch those.

Answer (score 1):

I have a nice example for makefile and GHDL:

"...Recently I added a makefile for this project. It is done based on the example c code interface for GHDL and IP TTL filter using VHDL. The makefile is described at makefile..."

http://bknpk.ddns.net/my_web/IP_STACK/start_1.html
and
"
 VHDL IP Stack Makefile
This is a makefile for IP stack project.

```
#variables
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -c -g
#-MD
SHELL := /bin/bash
GG = ghdl
GG_LIB = --ieee=synopsys --workdir=work
AFLAGS = -a --work=work
IFLAGS = -e
EFLAGS = -m -Wl,g_rand.o
```

..."
http://bknpk.ddns.net/my_web/IP_STACK/ip_stack_makefile.html